# ffmpeg-php and shell_exec

Tags: php, linux, shell, terminal, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg-php for uploading videos and converting videos from

> "ogv", "mp4", "avi", "flv", "ogg",
>   "mpg", "wmv", "asf" and "mov"

formats to

> "flv" , "ogg" and "flv" formats.

I'm doing this by:

```
        $command1='ffmpeg -i '.$Source." -ar 44100 -ab 128k -s wvga -aspect 4:3 -f FLV -y ".$dest;
        $command2="ffmpeg -i ".$Source." -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264  -vpre slow -threads 10 -s wvga -aspect 4:3 -f mp4 -y ".$dest;
        $command3="ffmpeg -i ".$Source." -acodec libvorbis -ab 128k -ac 2 -vcodec libtheora  -threads 10 -s wvga -aspect 4:3 -f ogg -y ".$dest;
        @shell_exec($command1.";".$command2.";".$command3);
```

When applying those commands on **.ogv** videos it works fine but when applying on **.MOV** it does not work and no errors displays although when I paste the command into the terminal it works fine.

**Hint: Script is running by cron job.**

is there any suggestions for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the script is running out of time before the conversion takes place.

Increase the execution time of your scripts.

Although its not a recommend solution for production. You might want to run background processes to do the conversion and use the PHP script just to upload the video.

Comment: Or the script is out of memory

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that this script is running by cron job so I guess its not related to the execution time

Comment: I would guess its more environment then. When running in Cron it possibly can't find ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

1. What happens when you run the problem part outside of a crontab?
2. are you saving the  output of your crontab entry to files? i.e.

   59 12 1 1 * { myPhpScript ; } > /tmp/myPhpScript.log 2>&1` ...

( The semicolon preceding the closing '}' is critical)

This captures any stdout or stderr messages to a logfile.

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a newish user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.